# How do I use page_callback or pageshow to display an existing article, view, page, block, or a slide show?

Tags: javascript

can someone give me these examples to show an article or a block, page that already existing in a drupal website using pageshow or page_callback?

I currently can only successfully showing a link of the article, and then it lead me to the node. Here is my custom js code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function intro_menu() {
  var items = {};
  items['intro'] = {
    title:'Introduction',
    page_callback: 'intro_page',
    pageshow: 'intro_page_pageshow'
  };
  return items;
}

function intro_page() {

 try{
  var content = {};
  content['my_stuff'] = {
    //markup: '<p>Nice stuff!</p>'
    theme: 'link',
    text: 'SlideShow',
    path: 'node/12'
  };
  return content;
 }
 catch (error) { console.log('intro_page - ' + error); }
}

function intro_page_pageshow() {
 // drupalgap_alert('My pageshow event has been called!');
}
```

After some trying, I can now do it with the following code:

```
    //page_callback
function intro_page() {
  return '<div id="my_node_3"></div>';
}


function intro_page_pageshow() {
 // drupalgap_alert('My pageshow event has been called!');
 try{
        var nid = 3;
        node_load(nid, {
        success:function(node){
         var content = node.content; 
         $('#' + 'my_node_' + nid).html(content).trigger('create');
          }
        });
  }
  catch (error) { console.log('intro_page_pageshow - ' + error); }
}
```

But it's just the content, not the whole node.

I am still trying to display a page of slide show... The problem is I cannot find the node id from a "page". I tried the "path", but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your app's front page to show a node, then you can just set the front page to that node, in `settings.js`:

```
drupalgap.settings.front = 'node/12';
```

Under the hood DrupalGap already has a page_callback (and pageshow) that can load and render all core entity types. As you noticed with nodes, you simply linke to `node/[nid]` to view a node.

As for blocks, DrupalGap does not interface with blocks stored in Drupal, instead DrupalGap can create its own blocks for display in the app: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Blocks

Comment: thank you. I already have done that, and successfully add a button in settings.js which will lead to the node.